# String of letters/numbers being added to the end of my filename

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
import re
import time
import requests
import os, os.path
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    MetaData,
    Table,
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    Boolean,
    Date,
)
import boto3
import random
import botocore
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import mysql.connector as connection

engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://"
    + user
    + ":"
    + passw
    + "@"
    + host
    + ":"
    + str(port)
    + "/"
    + database,
    echo=False,
)

try:
    mydb = connection.connect(
        host="",
        port=int(3306),
        database="db",
        user="",
        passwd="",
        use_pure=True,
    )
    query = "select * from rentalPropertyDetails;"
    df = pd.read_sql(query, mydb)
    mydb.close()  # close the connection
except Exception as e:
    mydb.close()
    print(str(e))

client = boto3.client("s3")
paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket="zillowhousephotos")

s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name="us-east-2",
    aws_access_key_id="",
    aws_secret_access_key="",
)

zpids = list(set(df["zpid"].tolist()))

keyStrings = []
picNums = [random.randint(10, 50) for _ in range(len(zpids))]

for page in result:
    if "Contents" in page:
        for item in page["Contents"]:
            keyStrings.append(item["Key"])
for zpid, picNum in zip(zpids, picNums):
    keyString = f"{zpid}/{picNum}.jpg"
    if keyString in keyStrings:
        zpidPicNum = keyString.split(".")[0].replace("/", "_")
        s3.download_file(
            "zillowhousephotos",
            keyString,
            f"/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse/{zpidPicNum}"+".jpg",
        )
```

I'm trying to download images from an Amazon S3 bucket and keep getting a string of numbers/letters added to the end of my filename?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/read_images_to_aws_rds.py", line 88, in <module>
    s3.download_file(
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 190, in download_file
    return transfer.download_file(
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 326, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 642, in _main
    fileobj.seek(offset)
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 378, in seek
    self._open_if_needed()
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 361, in _open_if_needed
    self._fileobj = self._open_function(self._filename, self._mode)
  File "/Users/erinoefelein/.local/share/virtualenvs/HomeFlip-71a8tVCO/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 272, in open
    return open(filename, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse/29417540_17.jpg.ed7c7cDb'
```

Looking specifically at this:
29417540_17.jpg**.ed7c7cDb**
What's going on with that? How do I fix this?

Comment: I think this error is actually coming from some other part of your code.  Please post the **whole** code and error trace message.

Comment: That could be a temporary name for the file as it's being downloaded, but for some reason that directory path doesn't exist so it fails.

Comment: @tadman The number/letter string is being added after the extension, hence throwing the error? Was my thought

Comment: The error message says it happens on line 397, but this code has less than 100 lines.  This is not your real full code...

Comment: all the other code is commented out @JohnGordon

Comment: I deleted the uncommented code and regenereated the error @JohnGordon

Comment: Does the `HomeFlip` folder contain a `notFrontOfHouse` folder?

Comment: It does @JohnGordon

Comment: Try a simpler path like `/tmp/x.jpg` to test.

Comment: Hmm.  Try adding this code above the `s3.download_file()` call: `import os; print(os.listdir('/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse'))` and see if the output looks as you expect.

Comment: It looks like the s3 module deliberately adds those characters on the end of the filename to act as a temporary filename, and then it renames the file back to the desired name after it is finished downloading.  So the extra characters, by themselves, are not the problem.  The real problem is that some subdirectory in the full path `/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `import os; print(os.listdir('/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip'))` ?

Answer (score 1):

For atomicity/safety, `s3.download_file` downloads the file to a temporary filename (which you're seeing) first, then renames the file to the final filename.

My guess is that `/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse` doesn't exist, so you can't create a file there either.

You might want to

```
filename = f"/Users/erinoefelein/Desktop/HomeFlip/notFrontOfHouse/{zpidPicNum}.jpg"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
s3.download_file("zillowhousephotos", keyString, filename)
```

to make sure the directory exists.